# Remove the self/other row in a comparison DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very simple script I am running (basically a test for a script with a much larger dataset)

```
import pandas as pd

Data1 = {'First Name': ["Chris" , "John", "Jane"], 
        'Last Name': ["Potter","Doe", "Doe"],
        'Age': ["23", "32", "31"]}

Data2 = {'First Name': ["George" , "John", "Jane"], 
        'Last Name': ["Hall","Doe", "Doe"],
        'Age': ["27", "32", "31"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(Data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Data2)

Comparison = df1.compare(df2, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(Comparison)
```

This produces a Comparison data frame that looks like below:

```
  First Name         Last Name        Age      
        self   other      self other self other
0      Chris  George    Potter  Hall   23    27
1       John    John       Doe   Doe   32    32
2       Jane    Jane       Doe   Doe   31    31
```

My question is if there is a way to remove/manipulate the self/other row?  I couldn't find anything on google either

Comment: access the columns with `Comparison[('Age','self')]`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think your dictionary can be immutable and can not be changed except in other ways such as the code below that I was able to change the zero index from the first name and then by printing that dictionary to
Kronivar is changing

`Data1 ['First Name'] [0] = 'Kronivar'`

In order to be able to delete the columns with the drop () function, the first parameter is to select the columns and then we set the value 1 to delete the corresponding columns with this command.

`df1.drop(['First Name'],axis=1)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the second level of your column index, use `droplevel`:

```
>>> df1.compare(df2, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True).droplevel(1, axis=1)
  First Name First Name Last Name Last Name Age Age
0      Chris     George    Potter      Hall  23  27
1       John       John       Doe       Doe  32  32
2       Jane       Jane       Doe       Doe  31  31
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `reset_index`:

Due to `reset_index` just works with indexes, you have to transpose, perform the reset_index and then transpose again:

```
Comparison = Comparison.T.reset_index(drop=True).T
```

This will reset your columns names. You will have to set the names again after the command.

Output:

```
       0       1       2     3   4   5
0  Chris  George  Potter  Hall  23  27
1   John    John     Doe   Doe  32  32
2   Jane    Jane     Doe   Doe  31  31
```

2. Other option is just rename the `Comparison` columns:

Simply set your columns names again after the `df1.compare`, with something like this:

```
Comparison.columns = [el[0] + "_" + el[1] for el in Comparison.columns.values]
```

Output:

```
  First Name_self First Name_other  ... Age_self Age_other
0           Chris           George  ...       23        27
1            John             John  ...       32        32
2            Jane             Jane  ...       31        31
```